# Horizontal ImageView

Tags: android, image, horizontal-scaling

I have a picture that is very very more large (2100 px) than long(700 px)

The matter is, i want to import it in my android project to display it on the phone.

To import it I use "Image Asset", and Android Studio resizes it to be drawable (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi...). The fact is, wherever the new size is, Android studio squares it by putting transparent component in longer size. And after, because of that, when I display it in a ImageView, there is a lot of transparency at the bottom at the image, and the component which should be at the bottom is not close to the "true" image!

How can I do to avoid the square resize of the Image by Android Studio?

Thanks for answers ;)

Comment: Examine the actual PNG files that are in your various `res/drawable.../` directories. Are the images there not what you want? If so, then the problem is in the Image Asset wizard. If the images there are fine, then the problem is in how you are applying the images, and to help you with that, we would need to see the code.

Comment: Hey thank you for answer. In fact, it's in the res/drawable that is not what I want. My picture is 2100*700 px, and in drawable, Android studio squares it with for example 192*192 (for the biggest: xxxhdpi). And to square it, Android Studio resizes proportionally: 180*60 and then puts transparency all around the picture to reach 192*192. And after when I want to display it, the transparency all around stays...and i don't want it of course! ^^

Comment: I prefer the picture stays 3 times more large than long, and adjust after in the component in which it is displayed!

Comment: The Image Asset wizard is for fairly conventional artwork, like launcher and action bar icons. You will need to create different versions of your artwork for the different densities and copy them into their respective `res/drawable-.../` directories.

Comment: I've tried to do that. But it doesn't change anything...By the fact that my picture is not square it modifies it to square it when I launch the program, by again putting transparent all around... And moreover it resizes it smaller to after expend it in my component. So my high-definition picture 2100*700 is displayed awful on the phone! That's insane lol!

Answer (score 0):

Set on the ImageView

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

or you can select one of this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have tried, but it doesn't change anything. In fact the problem is the transparency I want to remove (see the other answer if you want more details)